# Magento 1.7 Costum option not working

Tags: php, debugging, magento

I have this weird problem out of the blue.

Magento was working find until today. The problem is this:
Now it is like this:

[image: a]

How it looks after I remove the costum options in the admin panel:
[image: b]

As you can see, it has something to do with the **Costum Product Option** it has nothing to do with the design, since I changed it back to the default template and that is the same deal. Also I don't use any stock feature what so ever(tested this and also has nothing to do with it)
Now I don't know how to debug this, since google chrome (debug console) isn't reporting any strange errors (non even). How can I debug this?

Comment: Just switch to Magento default theme and check if add to cart button is being displayed.If not then its more of configuration or some stock value issue as stated in other post.

Comment: check inventory related details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product might be out of stockk.Thats why **add to cart** is missing and you may not have handled that in your theme.